# 1px gap between table cells

Tags: html, css, css-tables

This bug is really making my head hurt. For some reason my table has a 1px gap on the left and right side of the middle cell. I have no idea what is causing this. You can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/JdayW/1/

What I need to have is an image in the middle cell that acts as a "mask" so you can see the background image behind it. There needs to be a solid color to the left and right of the image that stretches to the edges of the browser window. I figured a table was the best way to achieve this.. but I could be wrong. The gaps go away when I put a background color on the middle cell or the entire table, but obviously that is not going to work for me because I cannot have a background color behind the image.

In the site I'm building this "mask" image with transparency will scroll over the the fixed background behind it. So I cannot just make the png a jpg with the background on it.

Is this happening because I have the table set to `width:100%` and the middle cell set to a fixed 300px width?

Comment: All you need is to set the cell's padding to zero. i.e. `td {padding: 0px}`

Comment: I've tried this. When I set padding to 0 it kills the width of the table.

Comment: The gap appears to be on all sides (top, bottom, left, right) of that middle cell as well.

Comment: Can you link to a jsfiddle with the `padding: 0px` added?

Comment: Yep.. here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/JdayW/14/

Comment: Don't know if the problem was solved, but if you have ~ padding: auto 0px; ~ the top/bottom will be auto and left/right will be zero

Comment: No its not solved. The auto 0px is not doing anything for me.

Comment: How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/JdayW/21/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For some reason, your `td` tags were causing the margins. Setting them to 0 and giving the left and right `td` tags a width of 50% seemed to fix the problem:

```
table {width:100%; height:300px; border-collapse: collapse; border-spacing: 0;}

td.left, td.right {background-color:green; margin:0; padding:0; width:50%;}

td.middle {width:300px; margin:0; padding:0;}
```

Working jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JdayW/34/

Answer (score 0):

have you tried setting a padding of 0px only on the center td ? http://jsfiddle.net/JdayW/45/

```
td.middle {width:300px;padding: 0px}
```

the left and right tds also have a 1px gap on every side, but since background colors includes the padding you don't see that, if you put a white space on each td you can set all tds to padding:0px http://jsfiddle.net/JdayW/44/